# Python append object creation to a list inside another class

Tags: python

Why doesn't this add the object to the list? I've played around with Quiz.**class**.questionlist.append(self) by adding self etc

```
class Question:

def __init__(self, question, answer):
    self.__question = question
    self.__answer = answer
    Quiz.__class__.questionlist.append(self)




class Quiz:
    questionlist = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.generateQuestion()


    def generateQuestion(self):

        q1 = Question('How many weeks are there in a year? [DMID Standard]', '52')
        q2 = Question('Do cows drink milk?', 'y')
        q3 = Question("Is the word 'madam' a palindrome?", 'y')
        q4 = Question("Biggest search engine?", 'google')
        q5 = Question('You are in a race. You run past the second guy. What position are you in?', 'second')
```

Comment: As per your current indentation, `Question` does not have an `__init__` method.

Comment: `Quiz` *is* a class; you just need `Quiz.question_list`.

Comment: That said, you don't need a `Quiz` class if you aren't actually generating an instance of it. A regular function that takes a list as an argument in place of `generateQuestion` is sufficient.

Comment: Why does the `Question` need to know it's part of a `Quiz`?

Comment: @chepner Thanks but I need to use Quiz class as it is required in my assignment.

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried removing the .__class__ but still doesn't work

Comment: How have you actually run the code to determine that `Quiz.questionlist` isn't being updated?

Comment: @PeterWood I don't get you. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @chepner print(Quiz.questionlist)

Comment: Did you actually *call* `generateQuestion`? You need to include a *complete* program in your question that would let a reader reproduce your problem.

Comment: @chepner Shoot! That was the issue all along. Thank you so much chepner! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question, you just need `Quiz.questionlist.append(self)`, since `Quiz` *is* the class object with a `questionlist` attribute.

You can use a much simpler, straightforward design here, though.

```
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, q, a)
        self.question = q
        self.answer = a

def make_quiz():
    return [
        Question('How many weeks are there in a year? [DMID Standard]', '52'),
        Question('Do cows drink milk?', 'y'),
        Question("Is the word 'madam' a palindrome?", 'y'),
        Question("Biggest search engine?", 'google'),
        Question('You are in a race. You run past the second guy. What position are you in?', 'second')
    ]

quiz = make_quiz()
```

A general rule is, a class with at most two methods, one of which is `__init__`, should just be a function. `Quiz` qualifies, so just define a function that returns a list of `Questions`. Wait until you have *several* such functions (that add to an existing list, or removes questions, etc) before thinking about creating a `Quiz` class to encapsulate the list of questions.